# Block based animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c-blocks

In apple documentation

```
setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:
Sets whether the animation of property changes within an animation block automatically reverses repeatedly.

Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods instead.
```

They mentioned like this... But my app supports from 3.0 or later. Do i need to use two separate codes( one for 3.0 and blocks above 4.0). How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using your existing code. It will continue to work; they would just prefer you to use newer APIs if you can (which, as you've said, you can't yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The "old" animations are just discouraged not deceprated, this is Apples version of telling you: "If you use block based animations you'll unlikely write spaghetti code and mess things up really bad."

It's just a friendly nudge into the right direction, as "blocks" were not available with the older compilers in the older SDKs programmers got used to the begin->commit style (like old opengl with glbegin, glend) but that's unneccessarily spaghettiish if you want to chain multiple animations.